# Inner join more than 2 tables in a single database

Tags: sql, inner-join

i want to innerjoin more than 3 tables in one select query in one database all of them are having rm_id as a common column but i want to display the rows of all tables in one sql query is it possible if it is then i would hearly request u to provide some code

```
select * from 
        bk_det inner join
        bk_rep inner join
        bk_sec inner join
        mut_det inner join
        rm_det inner join
        soil_det 
on
          bk_det.rm_id =   bk_rep.rm_id =  bk_sec.rm_id =  mut_det.rm_id = rm_det.rm_id = soil_det.rm_id
```

Comment: i have tried the above but its error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an on clause for each inner join. e.g.

```
select * from a 
inner join b on a.id = b.id 
inner join c on b.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `ON` clause for each join:

```
select * 
from bk_det 
inner join bk_rep 
  on bk_det.rm_id =  bk_rep.rm_id
inner join bk_sec 
  on bk_rep.rm_id = bk_sec.rm_id
inner join mut_det 
  on bk_sec.rm_id =  mut_det.rm_id
inner join rm_det 
  on mut_det.rm_id = rm_det.rm_id
inner join soil_det 
    on rm_det.rm_id = soil_det.rm_id
```

*Note: you will have to check the join condition column names since I do not know your table structure*

If you need help with learning join syntax, here is a [great visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Since you are using an `INNER JOIN` this will return records if the `rm_id` exists in each table.

You might need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select * 
from bk_det 
left join bk_rep 
  on bk_det.rm_id =  bk_rep.rm_id
left join bk_sec 
  on bk_rep.rm_id = bk_sec.rm_id
left join mut_det 
  on bk_sec.rm_id =  mut_det.rm_id
left join rm_det 
  on mut_det.rm_id = rm_det.rm_id
left join soil_det 
    on rm_det.rm_id = soil_det.rm_id
```

Comment: ya thanx so much helped me but y m i not able to see ny records..?? :-(

Comment: @RineyAhuja that is probably because the `rm_id` does not exist in all tables, you can try changing the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: ya i am getting the records but only the records for bk_det for rest of all m getting null every where and my all rows of all tables are populated with somewhat 30 rows plz help

Comment: @RineyAhuja does the same `rm_id` exist in all of the tables?

Comment: ya it does in all the tables

Comment: but a small problem is there all tables rm_if dont have same values the differ in some tables

Comment: If the value is not the same, then you will not return records.

Comment: YA YA SORRY SORRY I JUST NOW EDITED ALL THE RM_ID COLUMNS OF ALL TABLES AND INSERTED 1 COMMON VALUES FOR ALL rm_id AND YES.!! I GOT THE FINAL ANS THANK U SOOOOOO MUCH U ARE AWESOME :-) :-D

Comment: umm i was thinking that if i was able to not to call the rows repeatedly then is it possible what will change i mean as i am getting rm_id multiple times in display so can i have it displayed only once